# Why 'is' is faster than '==' for number equality test

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know '==' is used to check the equality of two values and 'is' is used to test the identity of objects in Python as pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) post. However they can be both used for comparing numbers besides their other applications. I did some tests using both of them to compare two integers and 'is' appears to run faster. Why is that? and if that's true is there any other reason to use '==' for number comparisons at all?

```
timeit.timeit('1 is 1', number=10**8)
2.3460144830169156

timeit.timeit('1 == 1', number=10**8)
2.9029528259998187
```

Comment: Because `is` checks reference equality, which is basically comparing two integers (the references), but `==` typically takes a lot of comparisons, and possible casting, etc.

Comment: "However they can be both used for comparing numbers" - sure, if you want to perform a bizarre comparison that [**is not** an equality test](https://ideone.com/QRxKYT).

Comment: you cannot use it to check equal numbers with the exception of a handful of small numbers ...`x = 5000*2;print(x is 10000)`

Comment: Try assigning `x = 258` and `y = 258` (or larger numbers) on *separate* lines (not `x = 258; y = 258`, and then check the value of `x is y`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Correct, but pedantically, pointers are not integers.

Comment: @chepner `257` will do :)

Comment: @Idlehands Could have sworn 257 was in the list of interned ints for some reason.

Comment: Also `x = 1.0; x is 1.0` will fail miserably.